# Plotly-Dash | 1 marker_symbol for every trace / line

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a web app, where I pass Plotly configs via. GUI.

Whenever I pass multiple data lines and 1 marker, it automatically alters the `traces` to having one unique `marker_symbol`.

**How can I have 1 `marker_symbol`, e.g. `circle`, for all lines?**

---

Below, is an example plot that is similar to what I want - but has unique `marker_symbols`.

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Oceania'")
fig = px.line(df, x='year', y='lifeExp', color='country', symbol="country")
fig.show()
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb3Wp.png)

[Source - half way down the page](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/)